# wrap spans around individual letters of a div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to insert span elements around every letter of a div's text, belonging to a given class, using JQuery.
But my code only returns words, not letters. What is wrong?

```
$(function() {
    var title = $(".js-split-text").text();
    var titleText = title.split(" ");
    var newTitle = [];
    var letterCount = 0;
    titleText.forEach(function(el) {
            var titleElement = "<span>" + el + "</span>";
            newTitle.push(titleElement);
            letterCount++;
            if (titleText.length === letterCount) {
                var newTitleText = newTitle.join(" ");
                $(".js-split-text")
                    .html(newTitleText)
                    .css({ opacity: 1 });

                var aniTime = 0;
                var offset = 500;
                $(".js-split-text span").each(function() {
                    var currentSpan = $(this);
                    aniTime += offset;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        currentSpan.addClass("animate");
                    }, aniTime);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: _"Im trying to add a span element for each word in a div's text"_ So they should be added to words. Kindly provide example of the expected result.

Comment: ex: <span>I</span><span>a</span><span>m</span><span>h</span><span>e</span><span>r</span><span>e</span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're are wrapping the spans around the words in the text with this code

`var titleElement = "<span>" + el + "</span>";`

If you want to wrap the spans around the letters, you should further split the words into letters like so

`var titleElement = "<span>" + el.split('').join("</span><span>")  + "</span>";`